# NodeJS Application securing and sharing

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, localhost

I have an NodeJS application that runs on localhost and I want to share it with another person. 
But I don't want to reveal my code. So how do I give it as an application rather than the code itself.

I need to make my application a binary file.One click run app.

Comment: If you are using the same network ip, share your comp's ip. Else host it.

Comment: The guy who needs the app is far away. I don't wanna host it . I need to send something like an exe

Comment: It's a web app not desktop app.

Comment: I don't think what you want to do is possible, you'll either have to send them the code (maybe run if through an obfuscation tool?) or host it.

Comment: Well I found it on my own [pkg-module](https://github.com/zeit/pkg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are modules out there which help in  converting node application to binary(exe) .
Some are
[EncloseJS](http://enclosejs.com), pkg

Comment: @Developerrrr Can I know what is wrong with my question?

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by using [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) after install it and run it; you can give access to your application URL and PORT for example http://localhost:3000 and then ngrok will give you a URL to access it from outside.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I needed something like EncloseJS and I am happy with it.